# Is there a way I can import price from google finance into google spreadsheet with 4 decimal places?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, stocks, google-finance

I have the formula to retrieve the data from google finance.

=googlefinance(D4; "price")

I am tracking some penny stocks and some of the prices have a price in 4 decimal places. When I import the price and it only imports the information with only 2 decimal places. How can I import the price with 4 decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

```
=round((googlefinance("asx:"&A2,"marketcap")/googlefinance("asx:"&A2,"shares")),4)
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation what your code does?

Comment: Market cap is the total value of the company - where the total value is Shares times the current share price. Doing this calculation basically is getting the share price

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but for those searching for answers like me here is the solution:

```
=index(importhtml("http://www.nasdaq.com/aspx/infoquotes.aspx?symbol="&$A2,"table",8),1,2)
```

`$A2` = being the cell that holds the ticker symbol.

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out. Here is the formula I used:

```
=index(GoogleFinance(D1, "close", today()-1, today(), "1"), 2, 2)
```

`D1` = Name of stock entered to pull information from google finance. Works like a charm!

Comment: the index formula you are using here is a non sense for me. The summary say: "Returns the content of a cell, specified by row and column offset."

Comment: That's strange it was working earlier... Do you have any other suggestions or formulas?

Comment: maybe an idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769645/how-to-get-taiwan-stock-exchange-index-in-google-spreadsheet/21775576#21775576

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what I am looking for. I appreciate it though